# Downloading a directory problems in Java

Tags: java, file, download, directory

I'm using this code I found from here on stackoverflow. However, it always returns that the directory doesn't exist. I have checked many times and it does actually exist. Any idea why? I can't seem to change anything more on the server. I have set the permissions to read for everyone. Is there perhaps a better method?

```
    //Screen3
    JPanel screen3 = new JPanel();
    JTextPane TextPaneScreen3 = new JTextPane();
    TextPaneScreen3.setEditable(false);
    TextPaneScreen3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
    TextPaneScreen3.setText("Professor Phys will be instaleld in the directory you have chosen. Please make sure\nyour launcher is in that folder or the game will not work.\nClick next to begin the install process.\n");
    TextPaneScreen3.setSize(358, 48);
    TextPaneScreen3.setLocation(0, 0);
    TextPaneScreen3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black),BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
    TextPaneScreen3.setMargin(new Insets(4,4,4,4));
    screen3.add(TextPaneScreen3);
    final JButton BackScreen3 = new JButton();
    BackScreen3.setText("Back");
    BackScreen3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(Acceptance.isSelected())
                cl.previous(cards);
        }
    });    
    screen3.add(BackScreen2);     
    final JButton NextScreen3 = new JButton();
    NextScreen3.setText("Next");
    NextScreen3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //ProgressBar/Install
            File srcFolder = new File("http://www.futureretrogaming.tk/gamefiles/ProfessorPhys");
    File destFolder = new File(filelocation.getText()+"/ProfessorPhys");

    //make sure source exists
    if(!srcFolder.exists()){

       System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
       //just exit
       System.exit(0);

    }else{

       try{
        copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
       }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //error, just exit
            System.exit(0);
       }
    }
        }
    });        
    screen3.add(NextScreen3);        
    JButton CancelScreen3 = new JButton();
    CancelScreen3.setText("Cancel");
    CancelScreen3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });      
    screen3.add(CancelScreen3);

    System.out.println("Done");
    JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    screen3.add(progress);
    cards.add(screen3);
    mainframe.add(cards);
    mainframe.setVisible(true);
}

public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
    throws IOException{

    if(src.isDirectory()){

        //if directory not exists, create it
        if(!dest.exists()){
           dest.mkdir();
           System.out.println("Directory copied from " 
                          + src + "  to " + dest);
        }

        //list all the directory contents
        String files[] = src.list();

        for (String file : files) {
           //construct the src and dest file structure
           File srcFile = new File(src, file);
           File destFile = new File(dest, file);
           //recursive copy
           copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
        }

    }else{
        //if file, then copy it
        //Use bytes stream to support all file types
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
               out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"http://www.futureretrogaming.tk/gamefiles/ProfessorPhys"` is NOT a file!  It's a reference to a service provided by a server using the HTTP protocol!

Comment: Correct but the post I used the code from said it would work with website directories.

Comment: The post looks to be quite wrong then.

Comment: Okay what can I do to fix it? Other posts I was looking at detailed doing a lot with bytestreams and transcoding.

Comment: That's right. You need to make a request to the server for a resource, which you read that result via an `InputStream`.  Take a look at [Working with URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/) for more details